# Warning: a promise was created in a handler at but was not returned from it [bluebird]

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

So I cloned this project from GitHub and ran 'npm install' which ended with a few warnings but no errors, followed by that I ran 'npm run dev', the 4 commands were executed without any issue but, I am getting this error once the server is started. I am kinda stuck at this point and would really appreciate some help.

**Here is the error I am getting:**

[image]

**promise.js**

```
function Promise(executor) {
    if (executor !== INTERNAL) {
        check(this, executor);
}
    this._bitField = 0;
    this._fulfillmentHandler0 = undefined;
    this._rejectionHandler0 = undefined;
    this._promise0 = undefined;
    this._receiver0 = undefined;
    this._resolveFromExecutor(executor);
    this._promiseCreated();
    this._fireEvent("promiseCreated", this);
}
```

**setup-classeur.js**

```
function refresh (cb) {
    Tutorials.list().then(list => {
        CACHE.List = JSON.parse(list).map(file =>
            Object.assign({
                ref: urlify(file.name)
            }, file));

        Promise.all(CACHE.List
            .filter(shouldLoadFile)
            .map(file =>
                Tutorials.get(file.id).then(content => {
                    CACHE.Files[file.ref] = JSON.parse(content);
                }).catch(console.error))
        ).then(cb);
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `cb` parameter! Use promises instead.

Comment: Did you have any look at [the documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it)?

Answer (score 3):

You created a promise here:

```
Promise.all(CACHE.List
    .filter(shouldLoadFile)
    .map(file =>
        Tutorials.get(file.id).then(content => {
            CACHE.Files[file.ref] = JSON.parse(content);
        }).catch(console.error))
).then(cb);
```

It wasn’t returned. That means, for example, that if it were rejected, your `.catch(console.error)` wouldn’t apply. You can start by returning it:

```
function refresh (cb) {
    Tutorials.list().then(list => {
        CACHE.List = JSON.parse(list).map(file =>
            Object.assign({
                ref: urlify(file.name)
            }, file));

        return Promise.all(CACHE.List
            .filter(shouldLoadFile)
            .map(file =>
                Tutorials.get(file.id).then(content => {
                    CACHE.Files[file.ref] = JSON.parse(content);
                }).catch(console.error))
        ).then(cb);
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

This still isn’t optimal, though, because there’s a callback involved. Ideally you would just return a promise from `refresh` and leave error handling to the caller, where it can potentially do something more useful than log the error. This also cuts down on repeated code.

```
function refresh () {
    return Tutorials.list().then(list => {
        CACHE.List = JSON.parse(list).map(file =>
            Object.assign({
                ref: urlify(file.name)
            }, file));

        return Promise.all(CACHE.List
            .filter(shouldLoadFile)
            .map(file =>
                Tutorials.get(file.id).then(content => {
                    CACHE.Files[file.ref] = JSON.parse(content);
                }))
        );
    });
}
```

Then you can rearrange a bit with Bluebird’s utilities:

```
function refresh () {
    return Tutorials.list()
        .then(JSON.parse)
        .map(file =>
            Object.assign({
                ref: urlify(file.name)
            }, file))
        .tap(list => {
            CACHE.List = list;
        })
        .filter(shouldLoadFile)
        .map(file =>
            Tutorials.get(file.id).then(content => {
                CACHE.Files[file.ref] = JSON.parse(content);
            }));
}
```

and refactor so `Tutorials.list()` and `Tutorials.get()` parse their own JSON:

```
function refresh () {
    return Tutorials.list()
        .map(file =>
            Object.assign({
                ref: urlify(file.name)
            }, file))
        .tap(list => {
            CACHE.List = list;
        })
        .filter(shouldLoadFile)
        .map(file =>
            Tutorials.get(file.id).then(content => {
                CACHE.Files[file.ref] = content;
            }));
}
```

and if you use Node 8.3.0 or later:

```
function refresh () {
    return Tutorials.list()
        .map(file =>
            ({ ref: urlify(file.name), ...file }))
        .tap(list => {
            CACHE.List = list;
        })
        .filter(shouldLoadFile)
        .map(file =>
            Tutorials.get(file.id).then(content => {
                CACHE.Files[file.ref] = content;
            }));
}
```